# SwiftUI - Cannot assign value of type 'some View' to type 'Image'

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have declared a variable of type Image? and when view appears, based on the condition this variable could be assigned different image with different modifiers. However, when I add modifiers after Image and assign it to a variable, I am getting `"Cannot assign value of type 'some View' to type 'Image'"` error.

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var testIcon: Image?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                self.testIcon
                Text("Hello World")
                Spacer()
            }.onAppear {
                if condition1 {
                    self.testIcon = Image(systemName: "hand.wave")
                } else if condition2 {
                    // Seeing error on this line
                    self.testIcon = Image(systemName: "calendar.circle").foregroundColor(.blue)
                } else {
                    // Seeing error on this line
                    self.testIcon = Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass").foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The lines on which I am seeing error, I tried adding "as? Image" towards the end. I don't get the error but testIcon is nil when I try to do:

`self.testIcon = Image(systemName: "calendar.circle").foregroundColor(.blue) as? Image` or `self.testIcon = Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass").foregroundColor(.gray) as? Image`

How can I set Image variable with different modifiers?

Answer (score 0):

The `foregroundColor` modifier can be applied to other view types, not just an `Image`.  You can use it on text or shapes or pretty much any `View`.

If you look at the declaration of [foregroundColor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/foregroundcolor(_:)) you will see that it returns `some View`.  The effect of this is that the initial type of the View that you started with (an `Image`) is no longer visible to the compiler once you have applied the modifier.

You could change the type of `testIcon` to `(any View)?`, which will allow the assignment.

However, the whole approach looks wrong to me.  Changing a state property in `onAppear`, potentially  invalidating the view hierarchy and causing an immediate view refresh is just a bit ugly.

In general you should try and avoid procedural code in SwiftUI views and aim for declarative code.

You could refactor as:

```
var body: some View {
     NavigationView {
            VStack {
                IconView()
                Text("Hello World")
                Spacer()
            }
     }
}


struct IconView: View {
    var body: some View {
        if condition1 {
            Image(systemName: "hand.wave")
        } else if condition2 {
            Image(systemName: "calendar.circle").foregroundColor(.blue)
        } else {
            self.testIcon = Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass").foregroundColor(.gray)
        }
    }
}
```